# ORA-12514 error while trying to feed data into database

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-12514

I'm trying to feed test data into my oracle (11.2.0.3.0) database and keep getting the following error:

```
SQL*Loader-704: Internal error: ulconnect: OCIServerAttach [0]
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Please edit your question and show your connection information, e.g. your TNSNAMES emtries. How are youb trying to 'feed test data'? We really need more info to provide any meaningful hints/answers.

Comment: @JanDoggen could you please tell me how to get this information?

Comment: You should have a file called *tnsnames.ora* on your client computer. Please post its contents, plus the connection information you're using in your client application.

Comment: also, it looks like you're using `sqlldr`, what is the command line you are using?